# Spacefactor & Unicode Curly Quotes

Tags: spacing, punctuation, unicode

Unicode curly quotes seem not to have the correct space factor. Consider the following minimal example (*not* using french spacing):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Or fontspec with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
\begin{document}

Compare:

``Is the spacing correct?\@'' he asked. % Yes, as it should be

``Is the spacing correct?'' he asked.   % No, as it should be

“Is the spacing correct?\@” he asked.   % Yes…

“Is the spacing correct?” he asked.     % Yes -- but it shouldn’t be
\end{document}
```

Is there a way—either in PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX—to give the Unicode curly quotes the same space factor (sfcode 0) as the straight quotes have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closing double quotes are at position `"22` in the OT1 encoding and position `"11` in the T1 encoding.

So

```
\sfcode"22=0
```

or

```
\sfcode"11=0
```

will do, according to the chosen encoding. If you want a magic for setting the space factor code independently of the encoding (OT1 or T1), then

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \sfcode\csname\encodingdefault\string\textquotedblright\endcsname=0
}
```

is what you're looking for. Here's the test document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Or fontspec with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX

\AtBeginDocument{
  \sfcode\csname\encodingdefault\string\textquotedblright\endcsname=0
}

\begin{document}

Compare:

``Is the spacing correct?\@'' he asked.

``Is the spacing correct?'' he asked.

“Is the spacing correct?\@” he asked.

“Is the spacing correct?” he asked.
\end{document}
```

With or without the `fontenc` line the output is the same.

For XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, setting `` \sfcode`”=0 `` is correct.

---

Let's examine the case of `pdflatex`. The definitions found in `ts1enc.dfu` and `t1enc.dfu`, which are loaded when the OT1 or T1 encoding are loaded is

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201D}{\textquotedblright}
```

but it's `\textquotedblright` that changes meaning depending on the encoding. For OT1 it's "typeset the character in position `"22`", which is equivalent to `\"`; but for T1 it's the character in position `"11`. This may be declared by

```
\sfcode`\^^Q=0
```

but it's inconvenient having to give different definitions. Fortunately, the cryptic instruction

```
\sfcode\csname\encodingdefault\string\textquotedblright\endcsname=0
```

accesses precisely `\OT1\textquotedblright` or `\T1\textquotedblright`, which is the symbolic name of the right slot, depending on the default encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, and my edit that found the command `\sfcode` was halfway to the answer. Under XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, the curly quote character `”` can have its space-factor code set just like any other character. Under PDFLaTex, U+201D `”` redirects to the straight double-quote `"`, which can have its sfcode set.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}

\usepackage{ifluatex, ifxetex}
\newif\ifmoderntex
\ifluatex   \moderntextrue  \fi
\ifxetex    \moderntextrue  \fi

\ifmoderntex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Constantia}
    \sfcode`\”0
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \sfcode`\"0
\fi

\begin{document}

Compare:

``Is the spacing correct?\@'' he asked. % Yes, correctly

``Is the spacing correct?'' he asked.   % No, correctly

“Is the spacing correct?\@” he asked.   % Yes, correctly

“Is the spacing correct?” he asked.     % No, correctly

\end{document}
```

Comment: While ``\sfcode`"=0`` will work with the OT1 encoding, it won't for T1 (in `pdflatex`).

Comment: @egreg: Can you explain to me why using the straight double-quote character directly won’t resolve to the correct encoding point?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon: In `OT1` encoding, `"` selects the closing double quotation mark. In `T1` encoding, however, `"` selects the straight double quotation mark.