# Why does the csquotes package change the spacefactor?

Tags: spacing, luatex, csquotes, frenchspacing

The `csquotes` package changes the `\spacefactor` of several punctuation characters when they are used inside quotations. In `\nonfrenchspacing`, the `\spacefactor` of `?` and `!` are changed from `3000` to `3002` and `3001`, respectively. In `\frenchspacing`, the `\spacefactor` of `.` `?` `!` `:` `;` `,` change from `1000` to `1006`, `1008`, `1007`, `1005`, `1004`, and `1003`, respectively. I have verified this via testing (see my MWE) and lines `653` to `673` of the `csquotes.sty` file. Although the change in `\spacefactor` is small (<1%) and hard to observe visually, it is probably not typographically desirable. I cannot imagine any publisher or style guide seriously recommending such tiny changes in spacing. Furthermore, unless I am mistaken, I doubt the package authors actually want this change in spacing. Maybe it is a hack or funny way of programming the `csquotes` package.

In my MWE below, I first display the `\spacefactor` of different punctuation characters. Notably, the closing double curly quote (`\textquotedblright`) has a `\spacefactor` of 1000 when it probably should be 0. (A `\spacefactor` of 0 means that the character is essentially ignored when calculating trailing interword space.) I haven't figured out how to change this. `\sfcode\textquotedblright=0` doesn't work for whatever reason.

I use `\@savsf` to create a workaround by defining `\enquote` without using the `\csquotes` package. I define `\enquote` such that `\textquotedblright` acts as if its `\spacefactor` is 0. (I've used American English style quotations.) This lets me create quotations without unnecessarily changing the `\spacefactor` and producing ever-so-slightly suboptimal typography. Of course, it would likely be easier to just change the `\spacefactor` of the closing double curly quote to 0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pangram{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
\usepackage{stix2}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=4pt
\raggedright
%\usepackage{csquotes}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\enquote}{ s m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\textquoteleft#2\textquoteright}%
%   {\textquotedblleft#2\textquotedblright}%results in incorrect trailing spacefactor
    {%
        \textquotedblleft{}%
        #2%
        \@savsf\spacefactor%stores current spacefactor
        \textquotedblright{}%
        \spacefactor=\@savsf%outputs stored spacefactor
        %\textquotedblright has a spacefactor of 1000 and I haven't figured out how to change it to 0
    }%
}
\makeatother
%\sfcode\textquotedblright=0%doesn't work
\begin{document}
I display the \verb|\spacefactor| of different punctuation characters with \verb|\nonfrenchspacing|.
\par
period . = \the\sfcode`\.
\par
exclamation mark ? = \the\sfcode`\?
\par
question mark ! = \the\sfcode`\!
\par
colon : = \the\sfcode`\:
\par
semi-colon ; = \the\sfcode`\;
\par
comma , = \the\sfcode`\,
\par
single straight quote \textquotesingle{} = \the\sfcode`'
\par
double straight quote \textquotedbl{} = \the\sfcode\textquotedbl
\par
opening double curly quote \textquotedblleft{} = \the\sfcode\textquotedblleft
\par
closing double curly quote \textquotedblright{} = \the\sfcode\textquotedblright
\par
opening single curly quote \textquoteleft{} = \the\sfcode\textquoteleft
\par
closing single curly quote \textquoteright{} = \the\sfcode\textquoteright
\par
\medskip
\nonfrenchspacing
Testing \verb|\enquote{\pangram{}<punc char>}\the\spacefactor| with \verb|\nonfrenchspacing|
\par
\enquote{\pangram{}.}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{}?}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{}!}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{}:}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{};}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{},}\the\spacefactor
\par
\medskip
Testing \verb|\enquote*{\pangram{}<punc char>}\the\spacefactor| with \verb|\nonfrenchspacing|
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{}.}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{}?}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{}!}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{}:}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{};}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{},}\the\spacefactor
\par
\medskip
\frenchspacing
Testing \verb|\enquote{\pangram{}<punc char>}\the\spacefactor| with \verb|\frenchspacing|
\par
\enquote{\pangram{}.}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{}?}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{}!}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{}:}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{};}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote{\pangram{},}\the\spacefactor
\par
\medskip
Testing \verb|\enquote*{\pangram{}<punc char>}\the\spacefactor| with \verb|\frenchspacing|
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{}.}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{}?}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{}!}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{}:}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{};}\the\spacefactor
\par
\enquote*{\pangram{},}\the\spacefactor
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I found that I can change the `\spacefactor` of `\textquotedblright` from 1000 (default) to 0 via this code snippet:
[Spacefactor & Unicode Curly Quotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59390/spacefactor-unicode-curly-quotes)

```
\sfcode\csname\encodingdefault\string\textquotedblright\endcsname=0
```

So

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\enquote}{ s m }{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\textquoteleft#2\textquoteright}%
    {\textquotedblleft#2\textquotedblright}
}
```

would have the correct trailing `\spacefactor` after the `\textquotedblright`.

Comment: The spacefactor doesn't change spacing. It is a number that allows you to detect chars "through" other chars. csquotes assigns different numbers to be able to distinguish the various punctuation commands.

Comment: According to TeX by Topic, "The stretch component of the interword space is multiplied by the space factor divided by 1000; the shrink component is divided by this factor." (see section on Spacing) If I understand correctly, the `\spacefactor` increases the interword stretch and decreases the interword shrink, even when used with `csquotes`'s `\enquote`.

Comment: a right, it affects that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do an experiment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\showboxbreadth=1000
\showboxdepth=1000
\tracingonline=1

\sfcode`?=3000
\setbox0=\hbox{a? x}
\showbox0

\sfcode`?=3002
\setbox0=\hbox{a? x}
\showbox0

\end{document}
```

The console will show

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x19.44449
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ?
.\glue 4.44444 plus 4.99997 minus 0.37036
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x

! OK.
l.12 \showbox0

?
> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x19.44449
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ?
.\glue 4.44444 plus 5.0033 minus 0.37012
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x

! OK.
l.16 \showbox0
```

The stretch component is increased by 0.00333pt, which is a tad less than 0.012 millimeters. It's indeed less than 1%, actually less than 0.001%. The space is not added as is, only a fraction of it would be used. Nothing to worry about.

To the contrary, different space factors can be used to know what punctuation sign is the last character. The same strategy is used in `amsthm.sty`, which modifies `\frenchspacing` to be

```
\def\nopunct{\spacefactor 1007 }
\def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.1006\sfcode`\?1005\sfcode`\!1004%
  \sfcode`\:1003\sfcode`\;1002\sfcode`\,1001 }
```

for the `\@addpunct` macro. The changes in the stretch and shrink components are negligible.